# What is the device that the Baron's servant is holding in this scene?

Tags: dune, dune-2021

What is the handheld device called that the Baron's servant is playing during his healing bath scene? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: [The shooting script](https://d2bu9v0mnky9ur.cloudfront.net/academy2021/scripts/duneMxFtT98NYwBsMltl20211109/dune_final_shooting_script_6_19_20.pdf) doesn't seem to offer much help.

Comment: My assumption would be some sort of non-computer calculator to aid his abilities, much as how abacuses and counting beads on rosaries were used in the past.

Comment: The bald servant is playing it.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=tCylH-WzqrU at the beginning of this clip

Comment: Out of universe, it's pretty clear that they have made these out of a set of magnets that you can purchase from MenKind; https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=7lysosAMgaM

Comment: I suspect this is a nod to 'semuta' an atonal music that can be combined with a drug to produce heightened sensations in the user.

Comment: I can't find any reference to the name of the instrument in the book, only to balisets, played by the likes of Gurney and in Dune Messiah, by [spoiler]. These are stringed instruments and tonal, not like the atonal stuff accompanying semuta.

Comment: Videos have a habit of disappearing.  Please edit a still in.